# How do i wrap the unparsed-text function in a condition so that it is not called all the time?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

Following up on question [How do i pass a dynamic filename to unparsed-text function in xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907292/how-do-i-pass-a-dynamic-filename-to-unparsed-text-function-in-xslt/77907384#77907384)

I have the below snippet of code:

```
<xsl:variable name="PDFNAME" select="InvoiceIndicators/PdfFileName"/>
<xsl:variable name="vText" select="tokenize(unparsed-text('../data/ebpp/fopinvoices/arn/emfe_afp/sample.txt'),'&#xD;&#xA;')"/>
<xsl:message>value of unparsed-text is <xsl:value-of select="$vText"/> </xsl:message>
<xsl:variable name="PDFFileStatus">
    <xsl:for-each select="$vText">
        <xsl:if test="contains(.,$PDFNAME)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,',')"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:message><xsl:text>PDFFileStatus :</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of
```

select="$PDFFileStatus"/> </xsl:message>

I am making use of the variable PDFFileStatus in other parts of the codes and and a check to it.

For example in some part of the code i have ,

```
<xsl:when test="DunningSummary and $PDFFileStatus='Found'">
                <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(DunningSummary)"/>
</xsl:when>
```

The code works perfectly so far. But i have some cases where i dont want to enter the code where i have written the unparsed-text function.

Like wrapping it with an if condition :

```
<xsl:if test="InvoiceIndicators/LetterTypeCode = 'PU'">
    <xsl:variable name="imagename" select="substring(substring-after(InvoiceDetails/InvoiceNumber, '_'), 3, 9)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vText" select="tokenize(unparsed-text(concat('../data/ebpp/fopinvoices/arn/emfe_afp/', $FileName, '.txt')),'&#xD;&#xA;')"/>
    <xsl:message>value of unparsed-text is <xsl:value-of select="$vText"/> </xsl:message>
    <xsl:variable name="PDFFileStatus">
        <xsl:for-each select="$vText">
            <xsl:if test="contains(.,$imagename)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,',')"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:message><xsl:text>PDFFileStatus :</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="$PDFFileStatus"/> </xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
```

But now i have the issue with the code snippet where i added a check to the variable PDFFileStatus.

How do i handle such case?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what the issue is. But variables need to be in scope, if you wrap a variable in an `xsl:if` it is in scope inside of the `xsl:if` but not outside.

Comment: The issue is that the unparsed-text function tries to look for a file which is not available in certain cases. Thats the reason i added the xsl:if block

Comment: File : '../data/ebpp/fopinvoices/arn/emfe_afp/', $FileName, '.txt') is not available in all cases. And its throwing an error in such case.

Comment: There is a function `unparsed-text-available`, I think. Like there is `doc-available` for `doc` checks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you want to use the function `unparsed-text-available` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-unparsed-text-available and then only use `unparsed-text` if the unparsed-text-available check returns true.